# gulp-protractor error with chrome v54 / web driver v2.25

Tags: google-chrome, gulp, protractor, chrome-web-driver, gulp-protractor

Due to the latest update of chrome (v54) we've noticed our protractor tests failing. We attempted to update to the latest version of gulp-protractor (v3.0.0) which in turn downloads the latest web driver (v2.25) to resolve the issue but unfortunately a new error occurs we've been unable to resolve.

Everything worked fine before chrome's update.

Our protractor configuration is as follows:

```
exports.config = {
  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
      var fs = require('fs');
      var testDir = 'testresults/';
      if (!fs.existsSync(testDir)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(testDir);
      }

      var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

      // returning the promise makes protractor wait for the reporter config before executing tests
      return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function () {
          // you could use other properties here if you want, such as platform and version

          var browserName = 'browser';
          browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
              browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.replace(/ /g, "_");

              var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
                  consolidateAll: true,
                  savePath: testDir,
                  // this will produce distinct xml files for each capability
                  filePrefix: 'test-protractor-' + browserName,
                  modifySuiteName: function (generatedSuiteName) {
                      // this will produce distinct suite names for each capability,
                      // e.g. 'firefox.login tests' and 'chrome.login tests'
                      return 'test-protractor-' + browserName + '.' + generatedSuiteName;
                  }
              });
              jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
          });
      });
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: [paths.e2e + '/**/*.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

The error is:

```
[13:27:13] E/launcher - Error: Error
    at C:\ws\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:55:37
    at _rejected (C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:844:24)
    at C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)
    at C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\ws\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
[13:27:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPrepare` is being evaluated in built/util.js in the `runFilenameOrFn_` function. The stacktrace unfortunately is not helpful but what this means is that `onPrepare` has errors. Looking at your `onPrepare` method, the error is made when assigning the browserName from the browser capabilities. In your code, `caps.caps_` is actually undefined. Because `caps.caps_` is undefined, `caps.caps_.browserName` is throwing an error. The capabilities object should be accessed as the following:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(capabilities => {
  let browserName = capabilities.browserName.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

Comment: While your code didn't resolve my problem out of the box it clearly called attention to the issue - apparently in a recent chrome webdriver update access to the private property 'caps_' became no longer possible. Probably shouldn't have used it anyway so the solution was:

`browserName = capabilities.get('browserName').replace(/ /g, "_");`

[Here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3036) is a link to someone else with that issue as well.

Thanks so much for your help! I never would have thought the onPrepare function would cause such a nebulous error.

Comment: No problem. `runFilenameOrFn_` error message is not helpful. This will eventually be improved on.