# E/launcher - process exited with error code 100

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor. I followed the steps mentioned in https://www.protractortest.org/#/
When I run the command protractor conf.js, browser opens and closes immediately. 
I am getting the following error in command line:

[22:41:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

I tried executing in Firefox by adding capabilities in conf.js

contents of files:

## spec.js

```
import { element } from "protractor";

describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', async function() {
    await browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    await element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    await element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(await todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(await todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    await todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(await completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

## conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    //useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    //directConnect=true,

    /* capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
      } */
};
```

Comment: Can you post the `onPrepare()` from your conf file. [It appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295638/gulp-protractor-error-with-chrome-v54-web-driver-v2-25) this error can occur if there is issue within it.

Comment: My conf.js has just following code:
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};

Comment: It appears that the documentation for this tutorial has not been updated since the latest Protractor release. If you are using the using a version of Protractor above 6.0 you will need to handle the asynchronous nature of the framework yourself (ideally using `async/await` style). While I am not sure if that is the cause of your issue it is a good place to start troubleshoot this

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment the documentation has not been updated to reflect the fact that in the latest releases the control flow (which was previously used to handle the asynchronous nature of protractor) is disabled by default. Now it is necessary to handle these promises yourself and the `async/await` style is the easiest long term.

Below is the example from the main site using the async/await style.

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
    it('should add a todo', async function() {
      await browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

      await element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
      await element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

      var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
      expect(await todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
      expect(await todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

      // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
      await todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
      var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
      expect(await completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
    });
  });
```

I'm not certain this is the cause of your issue but it is a good place to start troubleshooting.

Note: Will only affect if your protractor version is above 6.0

Comment: When I installed protractor using 'npm install -g protractor', the installed version is 5.4.2

Comment: oh this should not be an issue for you in that case. It may be helpful if you include your whole `todo-spec.js'` and `conf.js` files in your question.

Comment: Hi DublinDev,thanks for looking in to it.Have added the code in question.

Comment: Can you try removing the import line at the beginning? Protractor will do those imports automatically when it starts and that style of imports is not natively supported in NodeJS at the minute. This means that your code would need to be transpiled for that style of import to work but as you are using javascript and not typescript this will not happen automatically. It is better to remove it and try once more. Also if you are using version 5.4.2 and the `async/await` style you will need to include `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your conf to disable the control flow manually.

Comment: Thanks DublinDev. After removing import line,It is working now

Comment: Good to hear. Do take note of the last line in my previous comment though. You can get unexpected behavior using both promise handling approaches